# Iterating over dereferenced unique_ptr, that contains vector, in for range loop

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, vector, unique-ptr

Why doesn't this code work as I supposed?

```
for (auto it: *std::make_unique<std::vector<int>>(std::vector<int>({1, 2, 3, 4, 5})))
    std::cout << it << std::endl;
```

The vector object is destroyed before executing the first iteration of the loop

Comment: Note that C++20 allows to avoid this sort of pitfall via "Range-based for statements with initializer", as described here: https://herbsutter.com/2017/11/11/trip-report-fall-iso-c-standards-meeting-albuquerque/. That is: you would declare the `unique_ptr` separately, ensuring it lives for the entire loop, then use the dereference of it as the range to iterate.

Comment: Why not simply write `for (auto it: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5})` ? and for more complex cases, why having `std::unique_ptr<std::vector<T>>` instead of `std::vector<T>`.

Comment: Yes, it's a very contrived example, which demonstrates the problem area but in a bit of an exaggerated way. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for#Explanation) is equivalent to:

```
{
  init-statement
  auto && __range = range_expression ;
  ... 
}
```

For your range_expression, it would be

```
auto && __range = *std::make_unique<std::vector<int>>(std::vector<int>({1, 2, 3, 4, 5}));
```

But

> If *range_expression* returns a temporary, its lifetime is extended until the end of the loop, as indicated by binding to the rvalue reference `__range`, but beware that the lifetime of any temporary within *range_expression* is not extended.

What `std::make_unique` returns is a temporary `std::unique_ptr`, after the full-expression it will be destroyed. That means the `std::vector` managed by it would be destroyed too; even though the `std::vector` got from the temporary `std::unique_ptr` is bound to the forwarding reference, its lifetime won't be extended.

From C++20 you might work around using init-statement; such as

```
for (auto p = std::make_unique<std::vector<int>>(std::vector<int>({1, 2, 3, 4, 5})); auto it : *p)
    std::cout << it << std::endl;
```

Comment: From that page: "If `range_expression` returns a temporary, its lifetime is extended until the end of the loop, as indicated by binding to the rvalue reference `__range`, but beware that the lifetime of any temporary within `range_expression` is not extended."